# Changed Layout to 2colums-left.phtml but still getting 2colums-right

Tags: magento-1.9

Please check the below image [image]

I changed in my local.xml file from 2 columns-right to 2colums left but still getting it in 2 column-right please help me

Comment: is the theme used by you is VENEDOR??

Comment: please post your relevant xml structure, maybe there is something wrong... (for example catalog_category_layered, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then lets solve this I too faced this issue when using venedor theme.

goto `local.xml` file.

```
 <reference name="left">
            <!-- remove left navigation -->
            <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
            <!-- remove currency switcher -->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
        </reference>        

        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.rightnav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

find this code will be in around line no:219 then the reference will be as `right` make it `left`.

Comment: this thing worked thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Magento have calling two type of handler for on category,Using this it set page layout.

catalog_category_layered is calling Anchor cateory and catalog_category_default  for non anchor category.Please check there might be set 2col-right set

2.Please check at admin>Catalog>Manage Category>  Select a category and check on design tab .... Custom design tab.

Comment: amit already worked on this solution but there is no result

Comment: is this occur for one category?

Comment: no for every category

Comment: can you please put catalog.xml at here and local.xml

Comment: actually in my premium theme I have only Local.xml file the theme developers gave all the things in that file only however now my issue was solved thanks for your concern :)